# search in a textFiedl, a specific word

Tags: actionscript-3, search

I've got, in my AS3 code, a textfield that load sentences from a database (each sentences is a title.

How can I simply do a search bar for this TextField. When the user type the word "computer" (for exemple), it'll search in every sentences the word "computer".

Here's my current code :

```
function createListItem(index:int, item:Object):void {
    var listItem:TextField = new TextField();
    var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    myFormat.size = 25
    myFormat.color = 0x000000;
    myFormat.font = "Mohave";
    listItem.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
    listItem.text = item.title;
    listItem.x = 10;
    listItem.y = 140+ index * 40;
    listItem.width = 160;
    feedbackText.text = "createListItem" +item.title;
    listItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent):void {
        showDetails(item);
    });
    list.addChild(listItem);

}
```

and it displays a list like this:

```
"I sell a computer"
"I sell a desk"
"computer and apple"
```

(and know if I can do a search bar in order to display only the sentences with a specific word).

Thx for your help,

Answer (score 0):

First convert your list into an array

```
var str: String = "first sentence. second sentence. third sentence. fourth sentence";
var arr: Array  = str.split(".");/// to split the string into array items



function searching(val: String): String {
    var collectedString: String = "";
    for (var i: int = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].search(val) > -1) {
            collectedString += arr[i].toString()+".";
        }
    }

    return collectedString;

}

trace(searching("second")); /// input the key word 
trace( searching("sentence")); /// another the key word
```