# how to search for a specific word in a huge array?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

In AS3 : 
I've got a long text in an array.

```
var myHugeArray:Array = ["I love Apple
I have an Iphone
I eat a Banana
I'm John
I sell a computer
I sell an Apple
I love rock
I sell a car"];
```

How can I do to search a specifics words ? (like : show me sentences with the word "apple") --> output : "I love Apple" and "I sell an Apple"

Thanks,

**EDIT**

Here's what I did so far :

```
loader5.load(urlReq);
loader5.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,completeHandler2);

function completeHandler2(event:Event):void{
            loader5.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,completeHandler2);
            trace("Données envoyées");
            feedbackText.text = "Données envoyées";
                loader5.load(urlReq);
                loader5.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, complete);
}

function complete(e:Event):void {
    addChild(list);
    products = JSON.parse(loader5.data) as Array;
    feedbackText.text = "complete";
    for(var i:int = 0; i < products.length; i++){
        createListItem(i, products[i]);
    }
    showList();
}

function createListItem(index:int, item:Object):void {

    var listItem:TextField = new TextField();
    listItem.text = item.title;
    listItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent):void {
     showDetails(item);
    });
    list.addChild(listItem);
    str = item.title;
    bar();
}

function bar(){
    var arr: Array  ;
searchBar.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;   
var suggested:Array = new Array();
     var textfields:Array = new Array();
searchBar.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, suggest);
arr = str.split(",");
trace(arr);


         function suggest(e:Event):void
        {
            suggested = [];

            for (var i:int = 0; i < textfields.length; i++)
            {
                removeChild(textfields[i]);
            }

            textfields = [];

            for (var j:int = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
            {
                if (arr[j].indexOf(searchBar.text.toLowerCase()) != -1)  
                {
                    var term:TextField = new TextField();
                    term.width = 360;
                    term.height = 24;
                    term.x = 18;
                    term.y = (24 * suggested.length) + 135;
                    term.border = true;
                    term.borderColor = 0x353535;
                    term.background = true;
                    term.backgroundColor = 0xFF9900;
                    term.textColor = 0x4C311D;
                    term.defaultTextFormat = format;
                    addChild(term);
                    suggested.push(arr[j]);

                    term.text = arr[j];
                }

            }

function showList():void {
    list.visible = true;
}


function showDetails(item:Object):void {
    titleTxt.htmlText = item.title;
    detailsTxt.htmlText = "<U>prix:</U> " + item.prix + " xpf"+ "\n\n<U>Description:</U> " + "\n"+item.theDescription + "\n"+"\n\n<U>Contact:</U> " + item.mail+ "\n"+item.phone;
    }
```

So, my AS3 code go search for PHP variable with `loader5`.

All the items found by the php are put in an Array (`products`). 
And a list of all the products is created. (`createListItem`).

If I click on an item, it show me some details (price, description..etc). It's the function `showDetails();`

Know I've created a searchBar (autocomplete). 
An array is created (`arr`) that split the string (`str`).

Then it does what it does to search through the array.

Problems :
1/ Weirdly, not all the words are displayed in my searchBar. Some words are working, other not. 
2/ How can I do to call the function `showDetails()` when the user click on the suggest `term` ? (term.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showDetails)); doesn't work as the `terms` is not `item.title`. `ShowDetails` is showing details of `item.title`. (so how can I say that `term` = `item.title` ?)

3/ Do you see a way simpler than that ?

Comment: I can't find anything on Google about that. I'm only finding some codes to locate the word, but not to retrieve the complete sentence.

Comment: Here, I've edited my post. The code is a little bit ugly, that's why I asked for a method without showing my code before.

Answer (score 0):

Your `myHugeArray` is just string, so `split()` it with `\n'`, you got the 
ret array for example, then find the one contains the word you search, like "apple", using `indexof()` in each string

Comment: Consider making your answer a whole lot more useful by showing an example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the string into an array then search each item 
check this out
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34842518/3623547